# How to get a different number of spaces with the tab in Kate when writing in different programming languages

Tags: kubuntu, kate

I want to get a different number of spaces when I press the tabulator in Kate depending on the computer language I'm using. For example in a html file I want the tab to produce two spaces but in C I want it to produce four. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Via menu:

- *Settings* > *Configure Kate* > *Open/Save* > *Modes/Filetypes*

you can set it like in [this examle](http://kate-editor.org/2006/02/09/kate-modes-filetypes/):

```
Name: C, C++ and Java settings
Section: Sources
Variables: kate: space-indent on; indent-width 4; mixed-indent off; indent-mode cstyle;
File Extensions: *.h;*.c;*.hh;*.H;*.hp;*.hxx;*.hpp;*.HPP;*.h++;*.tcc;*.cc;*.cp;*.cxx;*.cpp;*.CPP;*.c++;*.C;*.java
Mimetypes: text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-java
Priority: 10
```